# Invalidate cache or add http request

Tags: css, caching, httprequest, pagespeed

I've come across this scenario multiple times with the current app that I'm working on.

I have a large chunk of new CSS I would like to implement into a page. I have two options:

1. Add CSS to existing CSS bundle (minified CSS from ASP.NETs bundle utility), thus invalidating cache for that bundle
2. Create a new bundle and include it in the page (in the body), thus causing a new http request

Which would you choose? #1 invalidates the cache, but prevents a new http request. #2 creates a new http request but leverages cache for the other CSS bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of new CSS you're adding but generally speaking I'd go with scenario #2. I like to use a CDN for the framework CSS file, and then use my domain to host the website theme CSS and a page-specific CSS file. Make use of parallel downloads.

```
<!-- 1 http request to CDN for main framework, gets cached -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.min.css"/>

<!-- 1 http request to mydomain.com for main theme, gets cached -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.com/css/themes/modern.min.css"/>

<!-- 1 http request to mydomain.com for page-specific styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.com/css/pages/product-detail.css"/>
```

Comment: I was kinda leaning this way too. Especially since the new bundle would appear in the body, thus not be a blocking request. I'll leave this open for a few days to get other responses. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the transmission rate.
In general it is much better to include the CSS in the `<head>` rather than a separate file.
When the CSS is in the head the Browser has all the CSS before it get the HTML.  This way the Browser can start rendering the page even before the base HTML `<body>` has completed loading.
If the transmission rate is too slow and it takes a long time for the CSS to get to the Browser then a separate file may be called for.
If the CSS transmission time is greater than the HTTP request connect time, is when to start looking at a separate CSS file.
Using a CDN will add another DNS lookup if it is not already in use for other content. 
Also be sure gzip is turned on.
`#1` does not invalidate the cache if the HTML page is cached. 
Cache does not do anything for a first time visitor, and a first time visitor may never be a visitor at all if the page takes to long to load.